# Database.merge on DuplicateRecordItems?

Tags: apex

I'm trying to implement a merge functionality through Apex that queries for duplicates in the DuplicateRecordSet object and merge their child records, but I'm unsure how to proceed. I tried doing some anonymous apex with just two records but I'm getting cryptic error messages

```
DuplicateRecordItem item1 = [SELECT Id, RecordId, Name FROM DuplicateRecordItem WHERE RecordId = '0018E00001EjhCpQAJ'];

DuplicateRecordItem item2 = [SELECT Id, RecordId, Name FROM DuplicateRecordItem WHERE RecordId = '0018E00001EjhCoQAJ'];
```

These two recordItems belongs to the same DuplicateRecordSet. However, when I try a `Database.merge(item1, item2)`

I just get an error along the lines of

```
 ▸    common.exception.SfdcSqlException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index::
 ▸    5
 ▸    
 ▸    {call cMerge.merge_stdentdatas(?,?,?,?,?)}: []
```

I even tried

```
List<Id> duplicateIds = new List<Id>();

DuplicateRecordSet master = [SELECT Id, Name FROM DuplicateRecordSet WHERE Id = '0GK8E0000006MZMWA2'];
DuplicateRecordItem item1 = [SELECT Id, RecordId, Name FROM DuplicateRecordItem WHERE RecordId = '0018E00001EjhCpQAJ'];
DuplicateRecordItem item2 = [SELECT Id, RecordId, Name FROM DuplicateRecordItem WHERE RecordId = '0018E00001EjhCoQAJ'];


duplicateIds.add(item1);
duplicateIds.add(item2);

Database.merge( master, duplicateIds );
```

which just returns

```
 ▸    Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
 ▸    add(DuplicateRecordItem) from the type List<Id>
```

Edit: If I change the duplicateIds type as such:

`List<DuplicateRecordItem> duplicateIds = new List<DuplicateRecordItem>();`

I'll get

```
 Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0GK8E0000006MZMWA2; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Id 0GL8E000000y4O4 is not a valid type of id for merging with the master record id 0GK8E0000006MZM: []
```

Probably because those are `DuplicateRecordItems` and the master is a `DuplicateRecordSet`? Ie, two different sObjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't merge the DuplicateRecordItem records directly; you're trying to merge the marked records. You'd want to do something like this:

```
Id dupeRecordSetId = ...;
DuplicateRecordItem[] items = [SELECT RecordId FROM DuplicateRecordItem WHERE DuplicateRecordSetId = :dupeRecordSetId];
Id masterId = items.remove(0).RecordId;
sObject master = masterId.getSObjectType().newSobject(masterId);
Id[] children = new Id[0];
while(items.size() > 0) {
  children.add(items.remove(0).RecordId);
}
Database.merge(master, children);
```

You may want to add additional logic to determine which record to keep as the master, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand this part though:
`Account master = masterId.newSobject(masterId);` 
What's that trying to do?

Comment: @erikvm Sorry, I had some typos. Try out the new version.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, always a trooper!

Comment: One concern: how would this query handle if you have more than one DuplicateRecordSet? Say I have 3 duplicates over 30 different accounts and I wish to go through all of them

Comment: @erikvm In terms of a bulk merge, you'd use a Database.Batchable, querying the DuplicateRecordSet, then for each set, query the DuplicateRecordItem records during the execute method. You'll obviously need to set the "scope" to a smaller value than the default 200. In our org, we have it set to about 10 or so, as we have a large number of triggers that have to execute for each merge.

Comment: But in terms of several merges across different records, say merging `Account 1` with `Account 2` and `3`, and then merge `Account 4` with `Account 5`? Should/can that logic be handled by `Database.Batchable` as well? 

Not just in terms of Merging Account 1-100 with Account 2

Comment: @erikvm You have to do each merge individually. Basically, the start method would return a list of DuplicateRecordSet records, and in the execute method, you'd query fro the DuplicateRecordItem records for each set, and merge one at a time in a loop.